# Matplotlib not installing via toolchain command while converting kivy app into iOS; kivymd giving problems too

Tags: python, ios, matplotlib, kivy, kivymd

I have an app which makes use of kivy and kivy md along with python libraries like matplotlib.

How and when do I install kivymd and matplotlib such that the kivy app runs on the Xcode simulator.

I have tried installing matplotlib and kivymd via the toolchain pip install  command but keep getting an error for matplotlib as:
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement matplotlib (from versions: )

No matching distribution found for matplotlib

kivymd on the other hand, even though gets installed via the toolchain command gives an error when the app runs on Xcode :

.8/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 114, in

```
 from . import _imaging as core
```

ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL'

Can someone please help me out.

there are no extensive tutorials which discuss how to convert kivy apps which make use of kivymd and matplotlib into iOS apps.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Until recently kivy-ios has not offered matplotlib as an extension.  This has recently changed, and a matplotlib recipe is now available as part of the master branch of their github project.

https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios

I encourage you to use the kivy support forums to get further help on this:

https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios#support